# how to find the nearest neighbor of a sparse vector

Tags: algorithm, vector, machine-learning, information-retrieval

I have about 500 vectors,each vector is a 1500-dimension vector,
and almost every vector is very sparse-- I mean only about 30-70 dimension of the vector is not 0。

Now, the problom is that here is a given vetor,also 1500 dimension,and I need to compare it to the 500 vectors to find which of the 500 is the nearest one.(In euclidean distance).

There is no doubt that brute-force method is a solution , but I need to calculate the distance for 500 times ,which takes a long time.

Yesterday I read an article "Object retrieval with large vocabularies and fast spatial matching", it says using inverted index will help,its says:
[image]

but after my test, it made almost no sense, imagine a 1500-vector in which 50 of the dimension are not zero, when it comes to another one, they may always have the same dimension that are not zero. In other words, this algorithm can only rule out a little vectors, I still need to compare with many vectors left.

Thank you for your nice that you have read to here, my question is that:

1.will this algorithm make sense?

2.is there any other way to do what I want to do? such as flann or Kd-TREE?
but I want the exact accurate nearest neighbor, a approxiate one is not enough

Comment: This question belongs to Cross Validated, not SO.

Comment: @EliKorvigo I disagree. This is a technical (indexing!) question, not a statistical question.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of index is called **inverted lists**, and is commonly used for text.

For example, Apache Lucene uses this kind of indexing for text similarity search.

Essentially, you use a columnar layout, and you only store the non-zero values. For on-disk efficiency, various compression techniques can be employed.

You can then compute many similarities using set operations on these lists.

k-d-trees cannot be used here. They will be extremely inefficient if you have many duplicate (zero) values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your context but if you don't care of having a long preprocess step and you have to make this check often and fast, you can build a neighborhood graph and sorting neighbors by distances.

To efficiently build this graph you can perform a taxicab distance or a square distance to sort the points by distances (This will avoid heavy calculations).

Then if you want the nearest neighbor you just have to pick the first neighbor :p.

Comment: thanks a lot, but my problem is that I compare a new vector with the 500 vectors, the new vector is not in the 500 ones.

Comment: For now I have no idea of how to do it in other way than testing every combinations. The best that I can tell you is that you can use the taxicab distance instead of Euclidean distance to "sort" the points efficiently, and you can even use SIMD instructions to improve performances.
With the taxicab distance you know that if we have 3 points A, B, C and C is more near to A than B then (A - C).taxicabDist() < (A - B).taxicabDist().
The taxicab distance is a really fast calculation as it only requires absolute value and sum.

Comment: Thank u, I am using the bag of words algorithm. In this algorithm I must use tf-idf to improve the acurracy. This meas after tf-idf the data are all float, but the SIMD seams to be a very good suggestion. Thanks a lot !!!